# Memcache localhost connection oddity

Tags: windows-xp, memcached, wamp

When I try to connect to memcache using this code:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

The call dies with the "Could not connect" error, but if I use localhost's IP:

```
$memcache = new Memcache; 
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

It works! So what's my problem? Well, this new computer is the only development environment I've setup that's been sensitive to that difference. I'm not about to go changing the settings on any code for what seems to be a computer specific issue, but I can't figure out what could be causing this behaviour.

I'm running XP, memcached 1.2.4, and wampserver 2. I've checked the hosts file; it does have an entry for localhost, and the dns cache has been flushed... Any ideas?

Comment: Odd question: If you go to the command prompt and type "ping localhost" does it resolve to 127.0.0.1 and successfully get pings back?  (It really should, but no sense skipping troubleshooting steps.)

Comment: Oooh, I think you might've nailed it straight off there! localhost resolved to "::1". Not sure what that means though...

Comment: One google later... ::1 is what localhost resolves to with IPv6. Quickest fix was simply to uninstall IPv6; everything works fine now.

Comment: SO makes you wait 2 days before you can accept your own answer, but today's the day! Thanks for the reminder. :)

Comment: @MatW Oh, I did not know.  Thank you for edifying me.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running "ping localhost", as Conspicuous Compiler suggested, revealed that localhost was resolving to **::1** rather than **127.0.0.1**. This is the correct behaviour for a network using IPv6, but it was this that was confusing memcached. As I didn't require IPv6 at all, I uninstalled it;

> Right-click on a Network Connection
>   > Properties > Highlight "Microsoft TCP/IP version 6" > Uninstall

All good again!

Please note; it may be that you can solve the issue less destructively by mapping **::1** to **localhost** as an entry in your hosts file. I didn't try it...